# Method Resolution Order in case of Base Classes Having different init params

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, method-resolution-order

I am trying to understand MRO in Python. Although there are various posts here, I am not particularly getting what I want. Consider two classes `A` and `B` derived from `BaseClass`, each having an `__init__` taking different params.

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "I am the base class"

class A(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, something, anotherthing):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.something = something
        self.anotherthing = anotherthing
    def methodsA(self):
        ...

class B(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, someOtherThing):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.someOtherThing = someOtherThing 
    def methodsB(self):
        ...
```

The question is, if I need to derive a Third Class `C` from both `A` and `B`, how do I initialise the `__init__`, if I have to? I can safely derive `C` from either `B` or `A`.

```
   class C(A,B):
     def __init__(self, something, anotherthing, someOtherThing):
         super(C, self).__init__(something, anotherthing, someOtherThing)
```

The above implementation gives me an error.

Comment: When you refer to "an error", please provide the full error traceback to aid others in identifying your problem.

Comment: Sure, for now, I have included the full working code below. I'll keep in mind to post any Errors in future...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jonrsharpe mentioned at the end of his post, the best way I've come across 
for handling this type of situation is accepting `**kwargs` and extracting 
named arguments explicitly.

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("BaseClass.__init__({},{})".format('', kwargs))
        super(BaseClass,self).__init__(**kwargs)            

class A(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("A.__init__({},{})".format('', kwargs))

        a = kwargs.pop('something')
        super(A,self).__init__(**kwargs)

class B(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("B.__init__({},{})".format('', kwargs))       

        b = kwargs.pop('anotherthing')
        super(B,self).__init__(**kwargs)


class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("C.__init__({},{})".format('', kwargs))

        super(C,self).__init__(**kwargs)


c = C(something=1,anotherthing='a')
```

Arguments that need to be extracted should be passed in named, so they appear in kwargs.

You can even explicitly accept only named arguments by ommitting the `*args` as in the example, so you catch yourself with a TypeError if you forget.

## EDIT:

After thinking on it a while I realize that my example is very specific to your example, and if you introduce another class or change inheritance it may break.  There are two things that should be addressed to make this more general:

## BaseClass does not call super.

For the example this doesn't matter, but if another class is introduced the MRO might change such that there is a class *after* BaseClass and it should therefore call super.  This leads to the second issue:

## `object.__init__()` takes no parameters

If we want to make the classes (BaseClass specifically) safe to put into a generic multiple inheritance structure where its super call might be dispatched to another class **or** object, we need to pop arguments off kwargs when we consume them.

This adds another complication, though, in that it requires that no two `__init__` functions share the same parameter name.  I guess the takeaway is that making multiple inheritance work in a general way is difficult.

Here is an interesting article (found through google) about some of the details: [article](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=281127)

Comment: Thanks bj0 for your clear explanation. I had another question. How do I print mro on the ThirdClass? C(*kwargs).__mro__ raises AttributeError. Is there any way to print out the Method Resolution Order?

Comment: Try accessing the ```.__mro__``` attribute on the class itself instead of the instance: ```C.__mro__```

Comment: Thanks very much... BTW I have now included my full working copy of the code for reference.

Comment: I re-discovered another good article about super: http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't use `super` for this. You'll have to use the "old style":

```
class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self, something, anotherthing, someOtherThing):
        A.__init__(self, something, anotherthing)
        B.__init__(self, someOtherThing)
```

Comment: This will not work. When `A.__init__` calls `super(self, A).__init__()`, it will get `B.__init__` and result in an error about the arguments not matching.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this, try without any arguments:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("BaseClass.__init__")

class A(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        print("A.__init__")
        super(A, self).__init__()

class B(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        print("B.__init__")
        super(B, self).__init__()

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        print("C.__init__")
        super(C, self).__init__()
```

When we run this:

```
>>> c = C()
C.__init__
A.__init__
B.__init__
BaseClass.__init__
```

This is what `super` does: it makes sure everything gets called, in the right order, without duplication. `C` inherits from `A` and `B`, so both of their `__init__` methods should get called, and they both inherit from `BaseClass`, so that `__init__` should also be called, but only once.

If the `__init__` methods being called take different arguments, and can't deal with extra arguments (e.g. `*args, **kwargs`), you get the `TypeError`s you refer to. To fix this, you need to make sure that all the methods can handle the appropriate arguments.

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe, for your easy snippet. However as mentioned, I had already seen the above implementation but wanted to go to more generic example as illustrated by bj0. Hence accepting his solution.

Answer (score 0):

While [bj0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21863327/1405065) is mostly right, manually extracting the arguments from `kwargs` is more complicated and awkward than is necessary. It also means that you won't detect when extra arguments are passed in to one of the class constructors.

The best solution is to accept `**kwargs`, but only use it to pass on any unknown arguments. When this reaches `object` (`BaseClass`'s base), it will raise an error if there were unnecessary arguments:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BaseClass, self).__init__(**kwargs) # always try to pass on unknown args

class A(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, something, anotherthing, **kwargs): # take known arguments
        super(A, self).__init__(**kwargs) # pass on the arguments we don't understand
        self.something = something
        self.anotherthing = anotherthing

class B(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, someOtherThing, **kwargs): # same here
        super(B, self).__init__(**kwargs) # and here
        self.someOtherThing = someOtherThing 

class C(A, B): # this will work, with someOtherThing passed from A.__init__ to B.__init__
    pass

class D(B, A): # this will also work, with B.__init__ passing on A.__init__'s arguments
    pass

import threading
class E(C, threading.Thread): # keyword arguments for Thread.__init__ will work!
    def run(self):
        print(self.something, self.anotherthing, self.someOtherThing)
```

If one of your classes modifies (or provides a default for) an argument that is also used by one of its base classes, you can both take a specific parameter and pass it on by keyword:

```
class F(C):
    def __init__(self, something, **kwargs):
        super(F, self).__init__(something="foo"+something, **kwargs)
```

You do need to be calling all your constructors with only keyword arguments, no positional ones. For instance:

```
f = F(something="something", anotherthing="bar", someOtherThing="baz")
```

It's possible to support something similar for positional arguments, but usually its a bad idea because you can't count on the argument order. If you had just one class that took positional arguments (perhaps an unknown number of them in `*args`), you could probably make that work by passing `*args` into and out of each `__init__` method, but multiple classes taking different positional arguments is asking for trouble due to the order they appear in possibly changing as you do multiple inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all for helping me understand MRO. Below is my complete Code together with output. I hope this will also help other's.

class BaseClass(object):

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs.get('name')

    def printName(self):
        print "I am called from BaseClass"
        print self.name

    def setName(self, givenName):
        print "I am called from BaseClass"
        self.name=givenName

    def CalledFromThirdGen(self):
        print "I am called from BaseClass and invoked from Third Generation Derived            Class"
```

class FirstGenDerived(BaseClass):

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FirstGenDerived, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name = kwargs.get('name')
        self.FamilyName = kwargs.get('FamilyName')

    def printFullName(self):
        print "I am called from FirstDerivedClass"
        print self.name + ' ' + self.FamilyName

    def printName(self):
        print "I am called from FirstDerivedClass, although I was present in BaseClass"
        print "His Highness " + self.name + ' ' + self.FamilyName
```

class SecondGenDerived(BaseClass):

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SecondGenDerived, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name = kwargs.get('name')
        self.middleName = kwargs.get('middleName')
        self.FamilyName = kwargs.get('FamilyName')

    def printWholeName(self):
        print "I am called from SecondDerivedClass"
        print self.name + ' ' + self.middleName + ' ' + self.FamilyName

    def printName(self):
        print "I am called from SecondDerivedClass, although I was present in BaseClass"
        print "Sir " + self.name + ' ' + self.middleName + ' ' + self.FamilyName
```

class ThirdGenDerived(FirstGenDerived, SecondGenDerived):

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ThirdGenDerived, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

if **name** == "**main**":

```
    print "Executing BaseClass"
    BaseClass(name='Robin').printName()

    print "Executing Instance of BaseClass with SetName \n"
    Instance = BaseClass()
    Instance.setName("Little John")
    Instance.printName()
    print "################################################\n"


    print "Executing FirstGenDerived with printName and printFullName\n"
    FirstGenDerived(name='Robin', FamilyName='Hood').printFullName()
    FirstGenDerived(name='Robin', FamilyName='Hood').printName()
    print "################################################\n"


    print "Executing FirstGenderived with instance\n"
    Instance2 = FirstGenDerived(name=None, FamilyName="Hood")
    Instance2.setName("Edwards")
    Instance2.printFullName()
    print "################################################\n"

    print "Executing SecondGenDerived with printName and printWholeName\n"
    SecondGenDerived(name='Robin', FamilyName='Hood', middleName='Williams').printWholeName()
    SecondGenDerived(name='Robin', FamilyName='Hood', middleName='Williams').printName()
    print "################################################\n"

    print "Executing ThirdGenDerived\n"
    ThirdGenDerived(name='Robin', FamilyName='Hood', middleName='Williams').CalledFromThirdGen()
    ThirdGenDerived(name='Robin', FamilyName='Hood', middleName='Williams').printName()
    print "################################################\n"
```

Output:
Executing BaseClass
I am called from BaseClass
Robin
Executing Instance of BaseClass with SetName

I am called from BaseClass
I am called from BaseClass
Little John

Executing FirstGenDerived with printName and printFullName

I am called from FirstDerivedClass
Robin Hood
I am called from FirstDerivedClass, although I was present in BaseClass
His Highness Robin Hood

Executing FirstGenderived with instance

I am called from BaseClass
I am called from FirstDerivedClass
Edwards Hood

Executing SecondGenDerived with printName and printWholeName

I am called from SecondDerivedClass
Robin Williams Hood
I am called from SecondDerivedClass, although I was present in BaseClass
Sir Robin Williams Hood

Executing ThirdGenDerived

I am called from BaseClass and invoked from Third Generation Derived Class
I am called from FirstDerivedClass, although I was present in BaseClass
His Highness Robin Hood